# send alert to html page from servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to create a registration page using java servlet. How can i notify about empty fields in form on my html page? here is a part of my code

```
       String uName = request.getParameter("username");
       String pass = request.getParameter("passwd");
       String rpass = request.getParameter("rpasswd");
       String email = request.getParameter("email");
       if(uName == "" || pass == "" || rpass == "" || email == "") {
         //what must i put here to send notification to html page
       }
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you need to return a new page. You can also do client side validation before submitting the form.

Comment: Agree with @Oleg. P.S. Remeber to use equals method when checking string equality and not '=='.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using *[request.getAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))* & *[request.setAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))* , for eg :

```
 String uName = request.getParameter("username");
       String pass = request.getParameter("passwd");
       String rpass = request.getParameter("rpasswd");
       String email = request.getParameter("email");
       if(uName == null|| pass == null || rpass == null || email == null) {
       //here you can set attribute like any error message
       request.setAttribute("error", "Please fill all fields in form");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("yourjsppage").forward(request,response); 
       }
```

And to show above `message` do like below in jsp page :

```
//this line will print whatever is in error :  Please fill all fields in form
<p class="text-center" style="color: green">${error}</p>
```

Alternative way to do `validation` in form ,you can use `required` attribute like below :

```html
<form  method="post" action=""> 

 <label for="userid">Name:</label>  
   <input type="text" name="username" required  /><br/>
<label for="passid">Email:</label> 
<input type="text" name="email"  required /> 
<br/>
<input type="submit"  value="Signup"/>

</form>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
   String uName = request.getParameter("username");
   String pass = request.getParameter("passwd");
   String rpass = request.getParameter("rpasswd");
   String email = request.getParameter("email");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession()
   if(uName == null|| pass == null || rpass == null || email == null) {
   //Here you can set session attribute like any error message
   session.setAttribute("error", "Please fill all fields in form");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Then add this line of code  in your jspPage

```
<p>${error}</p>
```

finally don't forget to unset session

```
session.setAttribute('error','');
```